# Want to convert sqlite code in Shared preference code

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I made a quiz application using sqlite data base but now have to convert this in shared preference. How can I change it to shared preference??

Here is my code

QuizActivity.java

```
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butNext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);

        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setQuestionView();

            butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
                if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                }
                if(qid<5){                  
                    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

ResultActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        //get rating bar object
        RatingBar bar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1); 
        bar.setNumStars(5);
        bar.setStepSize(0.5f);
        //get text view
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        //get score
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int score= b.getInt("score");
        //display score
        bar.setRating(score);
        switch (score)
        {
        case 1:
        case 2: t.setText("Oopsie! Better Luck Next Time!");
        break;
        case 3:
        case 4:t.setText("Hmmmm.. Someone's been reading a lot of trivia");
        break;
        case 5:t.setText("Who are you? A trivia wizard???");
        break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

DBhelper.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "CISCO");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "BIOS");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","Register");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?", "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","Router");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","BASIC");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Question.java

```
public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question()
    {
        ID=0;
        QUESTION="";
        OPTA="";
        OPTB="";
        OPTC="";
        ANSWER="";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC,
            String aNSWER) {

        QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        OPTC = oPTC;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id)
    {
        ID=id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        OPTC = oPTC;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }

}
```

activity_quiz.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/largetext"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton2" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radiobutton3" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayou
```

activity_result

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ResultActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:rating="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:text="@string/largetext3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you want to "convert" sqlite entries to sharedPreferences? A data storage of much infos is better stored inside a sqlite table. If you want to  store anything in SharedPreferences, you only have to read the row and put the relevant part into sharedPreferences.....

Comment: Why do you want to do so? SQLite databases are _supposed_ to store large amounts of data. Trust me, don't switch to shared preferences. Shared preferences are for _preferences_, not huge amounts of data like this.

Comment: shared preferences are not mean to do that, db are much faster and make more sense. Do you have to do it or?

Comment: its my task from my boss to change my code in shared preference i never used it before thats why i want help Opiatefuchshttp://stackoverflow.com/users/1538986/opiatefuchs

Comment: because its my task i have to change it its my boss order thats why

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper encapsulated Question model to JSONObject and then store JSONArray of JSONObject to single String shared preference. Add to Question.java new methods

```
public JSONObject toJSONJbject() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("ID", ID);
    object.put("QUESTION", QUESTION);
    object.put("OPTA", OPTA);
    object.put("OPTB", OPTB);
    object.put("OPTC", OPTC);
    object.put("ANSWER", ANSWER);
    return object;
}

public void fromJSONJbject(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    ID = object.getInt("ID");
    QUESTION = object.getString("QUESTION");
    OPTA = object.getString("OPTA");
    OPTB = object.getString("OPTB");
    OPTC = object.getString("OPTC");
    ANSWER = object.getString("ANSWER");
}
```

After that, rewrite getAllQuestions() to use JSONArray of toJSONJbject().
Because JSONArray doesn`t have unique key mechanism, you will need check data based on ID value.